# "Питерский" русский язык

Tags: грамотная-речь

Питерцы гордятся тем, что у нас самый правильный русский язык. Тем не менее, в их лексиконе много слов, отличных от привычных нам. Например, они говорят "кура" вместо "курица", "шаверма" вместо "шаурма", а одежду "водозлазка" они называют странным словом "бадлон". Это правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что "правильно"? Что питерцы так говорят? Да, это так.
Придраться, строго говоря, можно только к "куре". Остальное - на уровне городского диалекта, в Москве можно найти достаточно много столь же экзотических для питерца вариантов и выражений.
Правда, надо сказать, московские варианты в силу разных причин обычно быстрее становятся общеупотребительными.

Более подробно - посмотрите любым поисковиком "московско-питерский словарь". Их в сети сейчас немерено.